# Place label for text box above the box and not to the side

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As stated in the title i need to move the label for the text box to be above the box and not to the side. attached i have a picutres of what i mean. [what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbhrU.jpg) vs [what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scFj7.jpg) i have tried searching for it but i cannot seem to find the answer im looking for/not exactly sure what to look up. I have tried using JFrame but it made a separate window unless i need to make the entire GUI a JFrame for me to get the result i want?

Also the actionPerformed method has things but it is irrelevant to the question but displays correctly still.

```
import java.awt.event.\*;
import javax.swing.\*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Project4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JTextArea taArea = new JTextArea("", 30, 20);
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
boolean ch = false;
boolean pep = false;
boolean sup = false;
boolean veg = false;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
double cost = 0.0;

public Project4() {
    initUI();
}

public final void initUI() {
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

    getContentPane().add(panel1, "North");
    getContentPane().add(panel2, "West");
    getContentPane().add(panel3, "Center");
    getContentPane().add(panel4, "East");
    panel4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel4, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    getContentPane().add(panel5, "South");

    JButton button = new JButton("Place Order");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    panel5.add(button);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Clear");
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    panel5.add(button2);

    panel3.add(taArea);        

    JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Cheese Pizza") ;
    checkBox1.addActionListener(this); 
    panel4.add(checkBox1);

    JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni Pizza");
    checkBox2.addActionListener(this); 
    panel4.add(checkBox2);

    JCheckBox checkBox3 = new JCheckBox("Supreme Pizza");
    checkBox3.addActionListener(this); 
    panel4.add(checkBox3);

    JCheckBox checkBox4 = new JCheckBox("Vegetarian Pizza");
    checkBox4.addActionListener(this); 
    panel4.add(checkBox4);


    JRadioButton radioButton1 = new JRadioButton("Pick Up");
    group.add(radioButton1);
    radioButton1.addActionListener(this);
    panel1.add(radioButton1);

    JRadioButton radioButton2 = new JRadioButton("Delivery");
    group.add(radioButton2);
    radioButton2.addActionListener(this);
    panel1.add(radioButton2);

    JLabel name_label = new JLabel("Name on Order");
    name.addActionListener(this);
    panel5.add(name_label);
    panel5.add(name);

    setSize(600, 300);
    setTitle("Pizza to Order");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {


}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
         Project4 ex = new Project4();
         ex.setVisible(true);
 }
```

}

Comment: Following your own example, `panel5.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel5, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested `JPanel` with another layout in order to achieve that. I would go with `BorderLayout` here. You can also other layouts that allow vertical orientation. Visiting [the visual guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) will help you spot them.

```
JLabel name_label = new JLabel("Name on Order");
name.addActionListener(this);
JPanel verticalNestedPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
verticalNestedPanel.add(name_label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
verticalNestedPanel.add(name, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
panel5.add(verticalNestedPanel);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this I wasnt quite sure on how to go about this and got me exactly what i wanted